# 2d lights not working on white background in unity?

Tags: unity

I set the mainCamera background to solid color of white and added 2d lights ( lwrp and all that setup). I upgraded all assets to work with 2d lights.
I want to add lights on white background with red shade hope u know what I mean but i am not getting a high intensity. Its very dim and not looking good.
[image: 2d lgihts]

I want High intensity red lights on top right and left corner.

Comment: White will naturally wash out other lights. If you think of the RGB output of your screen, if your background is at (80%, 80%, 80%), then the brightest red you can add over that with a light is (100%, 80%, 80%), ie. only 25% saturation. The brighter your background, the less headroom you have left to represent saturated colours by adding more light to it. Have you considered using a darker background, or adding a darker object behind the light to increase the colour contrast?

Comment: I wanted lights on top of white color but after your comment I dont think thats possible

Comment: Red is darker than white, so you'll need to do something to compensate.

Comment: Yeah i understand